# Flatten an Array of Arrays in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a counterpart in Swift to `flatten` in Scala, Xtend, Groovy, Ruby and co?

```
var aofa = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
aofa.flatten() // shall deliver [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

of course i could use reduce for that but that kinda sucks

```
var flattened = aofa.reduce(Int[]()){
    a,i in var b : Int[] = a
    b.extend(i)
    return b
}
```

Comment: isn't it like using add object of an array ?

Comment: I did not look into Swift itself yet but in Haskell and F# it's ` concat` - so maybe look something named like this? - I'm rather positive that this is there somewhere (most FP langs. *know* about monads and this is List's bind)

Comment: yes in haskell it is actually called concat.

Comment: You should accept [andreschneider's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26041954/1271826).

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544675/flatten-any-array-swift

Answer (score 611, accepted):

Swift >= 3.0

**`reduce`:**

```
let numbers = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
let reduced = numbers.reduce([], +)
```

**`flatMap`:**

```
let numbers = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
let flattened = numbers.flatMap { $0 }
```

**`joined`:**

```
let numbers = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
let joined = Array(numbers.joined())
```

[image]

Comment: Just to state this more generally, `flatMap` is available as of Swift 1.2.

Comment: what's the difference between `joined`(formally known as `flatten`) with `flatMap`? Is it that while `flatMap` joins, it can also map/transform things. but here in the example we really don't need ie we return `$0`

Comment: @Honey: Yes, I'd say you're right. AFAIK `flatMap { $0 }` in this context is pretty much the same as `Array(map { $0 }.joined()).filter { $0 != nil }`. Please somebody correct me if I'm wrong though, that's what I understand under the documentation text line 'Returns an array containing the concatenated results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.'.

Comment: @Dschee `flatMap` will **either** flatten a 2D array into a 1D array **or** remove `nil` values, not both.  It determines which to do based on if the 1st-level array's `Element` is an array or optional— so if you pass it a 2D array of optionals _(e.g. `[[Int?]]`)_ it'll choose to flatten it to 1D _(e.g. `[Int?]`)_.  To both flatten to 1-D and remove 2nd-level nils, you'd have to do `array.flatMap { $0 }.flatMap { $0 }`.  In other words, the dimension-flattening is equiv to `Array(array.joined())` and the nil-removal “flattening” is equiv to `array.filter{ $0 != nil }.map{ $0! }`.

Comment: the answer is wrong and should be fixed according to comments

Comment: `flatMap` is deprecated and `compactMap` is recommended instead.

Comment: @Warpling `flatMap` is still appropriate for the use described in the question (flattening a 2D array to 1D). `compactMap` is explicitly for removing `nil` items from a sequence, as a variant of `flatMap` once did.

Comment: this answer doesn't flat array like [[1,2,3],[4,[5,6]],[7,8,9]]

Comment: @mohamadrezakoohkan that is correct. Since your array is of type `[[Any]]`, a `flatMap` simply transforms it to a type of `[Any]` ([1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6], 7, 8, 9]). And if we would apply `flatMap` again, we would act on an `Any? type, where the compiler does not know anymore if it is a simple value or an array itself.

Comment: Love the simple explanation! Thank you so much for sharing :)

Comment: @JimDovey, just to clarify: flatMap is *depreciated* meaning Apple doesn't want you to use it any more, for any reason. At some point it will disappear. So, it should probably be removed from the recommended answer

Comment: Flatmap is not depreciated for this usecase. Its just one signature that is depreciated . See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68938940/is-flatmap-deprecated-or-not-in-swift

Answer (score 35):

In Swift standard library there is [`joined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2431985-joined) function implemented for all types conforming to `Sequence` protocol (or [`flatten`](https://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/sequencetype/#func-generator-element_-sequencetype-flatten) on `SequenceType` before Swift 3), which includes `Array`:

```
let numbers = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
let flattened = Array(numbers.joined())
```

In certain cases use of `joined()` can be beneficial as it returns a lazy collection instead of a new array, but can always be converted to an array when passed to `Array()` initialiser like in the example above.

Comment: @chrisco can you please elaborate on how my answer is incorrect and what is the criteria for "simplest correct answer"? Can you please also tell how deleting an answer could impact the question in any way?

Comment: Try running your snippet first - what do you think it does?  What does it actually do?  What was the original question?  Is your answer correct?  If not, it would be better to delete it to improve the clarity of this post.  I have done the same with incorrect answers of my own.

Comment: @chrisco thank you very much for your suggestions, but I do run snippets before posting them anywhere. And my answer is correct as it returns exactly the same results as OP requested and using less code for that. I admit that my original answer was returning lazy collection instead of an array, although there was no restriction on that in the question. I still don't think that deletion of a correct answer improves the quality of the question in any way.

Comment: This was my point - that when testing / printing the output, you get an array of arrays: `FlattenBidirectionalCollection<Array<Array<Int>>>(_base: [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]))`.  Your point is valid though that you can access it like a flat array, so it would seem that that the `CustomStringConvertable` implementation is misleading.  Your code snippet was and is still missing a test though.

Comment: @MaxDesiatov Could you briefly explain what lazy collection is about and why it is beneficial? Thanks

Comment: @pixelfreak lazy collection's content is evaluated on demand, that means if only part of the collection is ever consumed, the rest of it won't be evaluated leading to reduced memory and CPU consumption. More information is available at http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/07/26/lazy-by-name-lazy-by-nature/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

Comment: As of swift 3.0, `flatten()` has been renamed to `joined()`

Answer (score 31):

**Swift 4.x/5.x**

Just to add a bit more complexity in the array, if there is an array that contains array of arrays, then `flatMap` will actually fail.

Suppose the array is

```
var array:[Any] = [1,2,[[3,4],[5,6,[7]]],8]
```

What `flatMap` or `compactMap` returns is:

```
array.compactMap({$0})

//Output
[1, 2, [[3, 4], [5, 6, [7]]], 8]
```

In order to solve this problem, we can use our simple for loop logic + recursion

```
func flattenedArray(array:[Any]) -> [Int] {
    var myArray = [Int]()
    for element in array {
        if let element = element as? Int {
            myArray.append(element)
        }
        if let element = element as? [Any] {
            let result = flattenedArray(array: element)
            for i in result {
                myArray.append(i)
            }

        }
    }
    return myArray
}
```

So call this function with the given array

```
flattenedArray(array: array)
```

The Result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

This function will help to flatten any kind of array, considering the case of `Int` here

**Playground Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 4.x**

This usage of `flatMap` isn't deprecated and it's make for this.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap

```
var aofa = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
aofa.flatMap { $0 } //[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 15):

**Edit:** Use `joined()` instead:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2431985-joined

Original reply:

```swift
let numbers = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
let flattenNumbers = numbers.reduce([], combine: +)
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5.1

```
public extension Array where Element: Collection {

    func flatten() -> [Element.Element] {
        return reduce([], +)
    }
}
```

In case you also want it for Dictionary values:

```
public extension Dictionary.Values where Value : Collection {
    func flatten() -> [Value.Element]{
         return self.reduce([], +)
    }
}
```

Comment: Although other answers are perfectly right, I love to use the extension +1 for that

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.2

I wrote a simple array extension below. You can use to flatten an array that contains another array or element. unlike joined() method.

```
public extension Array {
    public func flatten() -> [Element] {
        return Array.flatten(0, self)
    }

    public static func flatten<Element>(_ index: Int, _ toFlat: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        guard index < toFlat.count else { return [] }

        var flatten: [Element] = []

        if let itemArr = toFlat[index] as? [Element] {
            flatten = flatten + itemArr.flatten()
        } else {
            flatten.append(toFlat[index])
        }

        return flatten + Array.flatten(index + 1, toFlat)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let numbers: [Any] = [1, [2, "3"], 4, ["5", 6, 7], "8", [9, 10]]

numbers.flatten()
```

Answer (score 2):

Modified @RahmiBozdag's answer,
1. Methods in public extensions are public.
2. Removed extra method, as start index will be always zero.
3. I did not find a way to put compactMap inside for nil and optionals because inside method T is always [Any?], any suggestions are welcomed.

```
 let array = [[[1, 2, 3], 4], 5, [6, [9], 10], 11, nil] as [Any?]

 public extension Array {

 func flatten<T>(_ index: Int = 0) -> [T] {
        guard index < self.count else { 
            return [] 
        }

        var flatten: [T] = []

        if let itemArr = self[index] as? [T] {
            flatten += itemArr.flatten()
        } else if let element = self[index] as? T {
            flatten.append(element)
        }
        return flatten + self.flatten(index + 1)
   }

}

let result: [Any] = array.flatten().compactMap { $0 }
print(result)
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple Swift version 5.1.2 (swiftlang-1100.0.278 clang-1100.0.33.9)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0

[image: Screenshot]

```swift
let optionalNumbers = [[1, 2, 3, nil], nil, [4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
print(optionalNumbers.compactMap { $0 }) // [[Optional(1), Optional(2), Optional(3), nil], [Optional(4)], [Optional(5), Optional(6), Optional(7), Optional(8), Optional(9)]]
print(optionalNumbers.compactMap { $0 }.reduce([], +).map { $0 as? Int ?? nil }.compactMap{ $0 }) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(optionalNumbers.compactMap { $0 }.flatMap { $0 }.map { $0 as? Int ?? nil }.compactMap{ $0 }) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(Array(optionalNumbers.compactMap { $0 }.joined()).map { $0 as? Int ?? nil }.compactMap{ $0 }) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

let nonOptionalNumbers = [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
print(nonOptionalNumbers.compactMap { $0 }) // [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
print(nonOptionalNumbers.reduce([], +)) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(nonOptionalNumbers.flatMap { $0 }) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(Array(nonOptionalNumbers.joined())) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

`flatten()` was renamed to `joined()` in Swift 3 per SE-0133:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0133-rename-flatten-to-joined.md

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten nested array using the following method:

```
var arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [12, 22, 32], [[1, 2, 3], 1, 3, 4, [[[777, 888, 8999]]]]] as [Any]

func flatten(_ array: [Any]) -> [Any] {

    return array.reduce([Any]()) { result, current in
        switch current {
        case(let arrayOfAny as [Any]):
            return result + flatten(arrayOfAny)
        default:
            return result + [current]
        }
    }
}

let result = flatten(arrays)

print(result)

/// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 22, 32, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 777, 888, 8999]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more generic implementation of `reduce`,

```
let numbers = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
let reduced = reduce(numbers,[],+)
```

This accomplishes the same thing but may give more insight into what is going on in `reduce`.

From Apple's docs,

```
func reduce<S : SequenceType, U>(sequence: S, initial: U, combine: (U, S.Generator.Element) -> U) -> U
```

**Description**

Return the result of repeatedly calling *combine* with an accumulated value initialized to *initial* and each element of *sequence*, in turn.

Comment: With your code I get: `Use of unresolved identifier 'reduce'`

Answer (score -1):

matrix is  [[myDTO]]?

In swift 5 you can use this = Array(self.matrix!.joined())

Answer (score -1):

```
struct Group {
    var members: [String]?
}

let groups = [Group]()
let outputMembers: [String] = Array(groups.compactMap({ $0.members }).joined())
```

Description

If you want to make single array of the `array of object model`. Ex: we get `outputMembers` single array from all `groups`.

Answer (score -2):

```
func convert(){
    let arr = [[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7,8,9]]
    print("Old Arr = ",arr)
    var newArr = [Int]()
    for i in arr{
        for j in i{
            newArr.append(j)
        }
    }
    print("New Arr = ",newArr)
}
```

[image]

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.