# How do I concatenate or merge arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, merge

If there are two arrays created in swift like this:

```
var a:[CGFloat] = [1, 2, 3]
var b:[CGFloat] = [4, 5, 6]
```

How can they be merged to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: This is a subset of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24465281/78336

Comment: How do I do this and also eliminate duplicates when I merge the arrays, so that ```[1, 2, 3, 4]``` merged with ```[4, 5, 6]``` returns ```[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]```, which contains exactly one element of found in both arrays combined?

Answer (score 852, accepted):

You can concatenate the arrays with `+`, building a new array

```
let c = a + b
print(c) // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

or append one array to the other with `+=` (or `append`):

```
a += b

// Or:
a.append(contentsOf: b)  // Swift 3
a.appendContentsOf(b)    // Swift 2
a.extend(b)              // Swift 1.2

print(a) // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Comment: [AnyObect]? is not identical to CGFloat.  While concatenating to AnyObject arrays.

Comment: Khunshan: `AnyObject` indicates an object, which as I understand means something that is instantiated from a class type. `CGFloat` is not an object, it is a scalar value. As I understand it, arrays can contain scalars, unless it is defined as containing `AnyObject` or are further refined. However, I suspect here the problem is that the array is wrapped in an optional, so you have to unwrap it with `!` or `?` first.

Comment: Do we know whether Swift 2's Copy-On-Write intelligence extends to determining whether the `b` part of `a` is modified (therefore possibly eliding a copy of `b` during `a.appendContentsOf(b)`)?

Comment: @OwenGodfrey thanks. i have lil confusion over appendContentsOf and insertContentsOf.

Comment: [How can I combine two arrays each containing objects of different types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35402692/1077789)?

Comment: "appendContentsOf" always add the contents of the second array to the end of the first array, while "insertContentsOf" always inserts the contents of the second array at a designated position in the first, moving the contents of the first array at and after that point down the array to make roome for the contents of the second.

Comment: What if I have two arrays holding objects and I want to combine them not repeating the existing items. E.g. let `array1 = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]`, `let array2 = [Obj1, Obj3, Obj4, Obj5]`. I want the result to be: `combinedArray = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4, Obj5]`. Any pointers?

Comment: @oyalhi: If you search for "remove duplicates from array" or "array of unique objects" then you should find something to start with.

Comment: @MartinR sounds good. Thank you. In the mean time I filtered the second set from the first and then appended the first and second.

Answer (score 189):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you may choose one of the **six following ways** to concatenate/merge two arrays.

---

### #1. Merge two arrays into a new array with `Array`'s `+(_:_:)` generic operator

`Array` has a `+(_:_:)` generic operator. `+(_:_:)` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2963459):

> Creates a new collection by concatenating the elements of a collection and a sequence.

```
static func + <Other>(lhs: Array<Element>, rhs: Other) -> Array<Element> where Other : Sequence, Self.Element == Other.Element
```

The following Playground sample code shows how to merge two arrays of type `[Int]` into a new array using `+(_:_:)` generic operator:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [4, 5, 6]

let flattenArray = array1 + array2
print(flattenArray) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

### #2. Append the elements of an array into an existing array with `Array`'s `+=(_:_:)` generic operator

`Array` has a `+=(_:_:)` generic operator. `+=(_:_:)` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2963463):

> Appends the elements of a sequence to a range-replaceable collection.

```
static func += <Other>(lhs: inout Array<Element>, rhs: Other) where Other : Sequence, Self.Element == Other.Element
```

The following Playground sample code shows how to append the elements of an array of type `[Int]` into an existing array using `+=(_:_:)` generic operator:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [4, 5, 6]

array1 += array2
print(array1) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

### #3. Append an array to another array with `Array`'s `append(contentsOf:)` method

Swift `Array` has an `append(contentsOf:)` method. `append(contentsOf:)` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126941-append):

> Adds the elements of a sequence or collection to the end of this collection.

```
mutating func append<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where S : Sequence, Self.Element == S.Element
```

The following Playground sample code shows how to append an array to another array of type `[Int]` using `append(contentsOf:)` method:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [4, 5, 6]

array1.append(contentsOf: array2)
print(array1) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

### #4. Merge two arrays into a new array with `Sequence`'s `flatMap(_:)` method

Swift provides a `flatMap(_:)` method for all types that conform to `Sequence` protocol (including `Array`). `flatMap(_:)` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap):

> Returns an array containing the concatenated results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

```
func flatMap<SegmentOfResult>(_ transform: (Self.Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Element] where SegmentOfResult : Sequence
```

The following Playground sample code shows how to merge two arrays of type `[Int]` into a new array using `flatMap(_:)` method:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [4, 5, 6]

let flattenArray = [array1, array2].flatMap({ (element: [Int]) -> [Int] in
    return element
})
print(flattenArray) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

### #5. Merge two arrays into a new array with `Sequence`'s `joined()` method  and `Array`'s `init(_:)` initializer

Swift provides a `joined()` method for all types that conform to `Sequence` protocol (including `Array`). `joined()` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2431985-joined):

> Returns the elements of this sequence of sequences, concatenated.

```
func joined() -> FlattenSequence<Self>
```

Besides, Swift `Array` has a `init(_:)` initializer. `init(_:)` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2907560-init):

> Creates an array containing the elements of a sequence.

```
init<S>(_ s: S) where Element == S.Element, S : Sequence
```

Therefore, the following Playground sample code shows how to merge two arrays of type `[Int]` into a new array using `joined()` method and `init(_:)` initializer:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [4, 5, 6]

let flattenCollection = [array1, array2].joined() // type: FlattenBidirectionalCollection<[Array<Int>]>
let flattenArray = Array(flattenCollection)
print(flattenArray) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

### #6. Merge two arrays into a new array with `Array`'s `reduce(_:_:)` method

Swift `Array` has a `reduce(_:_:)` method. `reduce(_:_:)` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2298686-reduce):

> Returns the result of combining the elements of the sequence using the given closure.

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

The following Playground code shows how to merge two arrays of type `[Int]` into a new array using `reduce(_:_:)` method:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [4, 5, 6]

let flattenArray = [array1, array2].reduce([], { (result: [Int], element: [Int]) -> [Int] in
    return result + element
})
print(flattenArray) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this code, good explanation, just adition to your answer, it would be best, if you say which one is more efficient by performance?

Comment: I like `+` for 2 arrays and `joined()` for an array of arrays.

Comment: If you're merging more than 2 arrays (or strings or whatever else), restrain yorself from using the `+` operator, it generates absolutely insane compile times.

Comment: @lawicko which method will you recommend?

Comment: @CyberMew Anything that doesn't use overloaded operators, I like method #3 because I think it's most readable, but I also like method #4 with the flat map. For strings I like method #5 because at the end you get the joined string straight away.

Answer (score 44):

If you are not a big fan of operator overloading, or just more of a functional type:

```
// use flatMap
let result = [
    ["merge", "me"], 
    ["We", "shall", "unite"],
    ["magic"]
].flatMap { $0 }
// Output: ["merge", "me", "We", "shall", "unite", "magic"]

// ... or reduce
[[1],[2],[3]].reduce([], +)
// Output: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 24):

My favorite method since Swift 2.0 is [flatten](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/CollectionType/s:FeRq_Ss14CollectionTypeqq_Ss9Indexable5IndexSs22BidirectionalIndexTypeqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementS_qqqq_S_9GeneratorS2_7ElementS0_5IndexS1__SsS_7flattenuRq_S_qq_S0_5IndexS1_qqq_S_9GeneratorS2_7ElementS_qqqq_S_9GeneratorS2_7ElementS0_5IndexS1__Fq_FT_GVSs30FlattenBidirectionalCollectionq__)

```
var a:[CGFloat] = [1, 2, 3]
var b:[CGFloat] = [4, 5, 6]

let c = [a, b].flatten()
```

This will return `FlattenBidirectionalCollection` so if you just want a `CollectionType` this will be enough and you will have lazy evaluation for free. If you need exactly the Array you can do this:

```
let c = Array([a, b].flatten())
```

Comment: `flatten()` doesn't seem to exist anymore nowadays. But you may consider [`joined()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945737-joined).

Answer (score 19):

To complete the list of possible alternatives, `reduce` could be used to implement the behavior of *flatten*:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"] 
var b = ["d", "e", "f"]

let res = [a, b].reduce([],combine:+)
```

The best alternative (performance/memory-wise) among the ones presented is simply `flatten`, that just wrap the original arrays lazily without creating a new array structure.

But notice that *flatten* **does not return** a `LazyCollection`, so that lazy behavior will not be propagated to the next operation along the chain (map, flatMap, filter, etc...).

If lazyness makes sense in your particular case, just remember to prepend or append a `.lazy` to `flatten()`, for example, modifying Tomasz sample this way:

```
let c = [a, b].lazy.flatten()
```

Comment: How well does this answer still stand in 2019 with Swift 5.1?

Comment: flatten() doesn't exist any more. joined() can be used instead of flatten()

Comment: @uraimo if used let res = [a,b]reduce([], +) is it ignore empty Array and added valued one ?

Answer (score 12):

So this problem really cries for `flatMap`, no need to reimplement something by ourselfes or using reduce:

```swift
var a:[CGFloat] = [1, 2, 3]
var b:[CGFloat] = [4, 5, 6]
let merged = [a, b].flatMap { $0 }
```

That's it - have fun

Answer (score 11):

Swift 4.X

easiest way I know is to just use the + sign

```
var Array1 = ["Item 1", "Item 2"]
var Array2 = ["Thing 1", "Thing 2"]

var Array3 = Array1 + Array2

// Array 3 will just be them combined :)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5 Array Extension**

```
extension Array where Element: Sequence {
    func joined() -> Array<Element.Element> {
        return self.reduce([], +)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
print(array.joined())

//result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: A tiny nitpick - I believe if your function actually returns an array it should be called **joined()** instead of **join()**

Comment: See the naming guidelines for Swift here: https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#strive-for-fluent-usage - compare "sort" and "sorted" methods, one mutates the array, one produces a new array. "When the operation is naturally described by a verb, use the verb’s imperative for the mutating method and apply the “ed” or “ing” suffix to name its nonmutating counterpart"

Answer (score 5):

If you want the second array to be inserted after a particular index you can do this (as of Swift 2.2):

```
let index = 1
if 0 ... a.count ~= index {
     a[index..<index] = b[0..<b.count]
}
print(a) // [1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**

You can create a new array by adding together two existing arrays with compatible types with the addition operator (`+`). The new array's type is inferred from the type of the two array you add together,

```
let arr0 = Array(repeating: 1, count: 3) // [1, 1, 1]
let arr1 = Array(repeating: 2, count: 6)//[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
let arr2 = arr0 + arr1 //[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

this is the right results of above codes.

Answer (score 4):

```
var arrayOne = [1,2,3]
var arrayTwo = [4,5,6]
```

if you want result as : [1,2,3,[4,5,6]]

```
arrayOne.append(arrayTwo)
```

above code will convert arrayOne as a single element and add it to the end of arrayTwo.

if you want result as : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] then,

```
arrayOne.append(contentsOf: arrayTwo)
```

above code will add all the elements of arrayOne at the end of arrayTwo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the shortest way to merge two arrays.

```
 var array1 = [1,2,3]
 let array2 = [4,5,6]
```

Concatenate/merge them

```
array1 += array2
New value of array1 is [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with large sequences, then a more efficient way would be to use [chain](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chain.md) method defined in the Algorithms package by Apple.

```
let n1 = [1, 2, 3]
let n2 = [4, 5, 6]

let allNumbers = chain(n1, n2)
for num in allNumbers {
    print(num) // for loop prints 1 to 6
}

// Similarly for String type
let s = chain("foo", "BAR") // produces "fooBAR"
```

### Benefits of Chain over other methods:

1. Permits mixing of different sequence types

```
let n = chain([10, 20, 30], 1...3) // will produce 10, 20, 30, 1, 2, 3
```

2. Makes no new memory allocations

The `chain` method essentially iterates the first sequence and when it encounters endIndex in the first sequence it starts iterating the second sequence seamlessly.

Comment: It's amazing everyone doesn't use this every day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, with dictionaries of arrays one can:

```
var dict1 = [String:[Int]]()
var dict2 = [String:[Int]]()
dict1["key"] = [1,2,3]
dict2["key"] = [4,5,6]
dict1["key"] = dict1["key"]! + dict2["key"]!
print(dict1["key"]!)
```

and you can iterate over dict1 and add dict2 if the "key" matches

Answer (score -1):

Marge array that are different data types :

```
var arrayInt = [Int]()
arrayInt.append(6)
var testArray = ["a",true,3,"b"] as [Any]
testArray.append(someInt)
```

Output :

```
["a", true, 3, "b", "hi", 3, [6]]
```