# Combining two arrays of different types

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I have two arrays. One array called `albums` which contains objects of type `Album`. The other one is called `photosAlbums` which contains objects of type `PHAlbum`. These types are custom classes.

I want to combine the two to form a single array. I have declared an `AnyObject` array called `allAlbums` and trying to put the contents of those two arrays in to this one but it's not working.

I tried these methods.

1). Assigned the content of `albums` array to `allAlbums` first and then try to append the other array.

```
self.allAlbums = albums
self.allAlbums.appendContentsOf(photosAlbums)
```

But I'm getting the error **Cannot invoke 'appendContentsOf' with an argument list of type '([PHAlbum])'** here.

2). The method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404813/1077789).

```
self.allAlbums = [albums, photosAlbums].flatMap { $0 }
```

The type of the combined array becomes `[Element]`.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Maybe not exactly a direct answer to your question, but have you tried to make both classes conform to a custom protocol? Then your array can be `[CustomProtocol]` instead of `[AnyObjects]`.

Comment: The "duplicate" hopefully answers your question. In your case it would be `self.allAlbums.appendContentsOf(photosAlbums as [AnyObject])`.

Comment: You can set the type for PhotoAlbums array as [AnyObject]. This'll resolved your issue