# Swift Define Array with more than one Integer Range one liner

Tags: ios, swift

I have an Array which I have defined

```
  var array: [Int] = Array(1...24)
```

I then add

```
   array.insert(9999, atIndex: 0)
```

I would like to do something like

```
  var array: [Int] = Array(9999...9999,1...24)
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Do you want an array of ranges?

Comment: What exactly do you mean via `9999...9999`? From 9999 to 9999 there is only 9999, so the result of your code is `[9999, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]` what is same as this what you want (as far as I understand the question).

Comment: The question is pretty unclear

Comment: You can simply concatenate arrays, e.g. `Array(100 ... 110) + Array(1 ... 24)`, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146382/how-do-i-concatenate-or-merge-arrays-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR ,  Do not see why it is a duplicate :" How do I concatenate or merge arrays in Swift"

Comment: Yesss, now I can dish out the down votes!

Comment: @RyanHeitner Oh man that's hilarious! btw, I didn't down vote your question.

Comment: @RyanHeitner That literally made me lol

Comment: Sorry I thought it was you you gave the comment, above and then I saw I was downvoted put 1 and 1 together and got 3

Comment: Out of spite should... should I down vote you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MartinR mentioned, you could simply concenate arrays using the `+` operator; and if this method is an answer for you, than this thread is a duplicate (see [MartinR:s link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146382/how-do-i-concatenate-or-merge-arrays-in-swift)), and should be closed.

---

If you explicitly wants to initialize an `Int` array using several ranges at once (see e.g. hola:s answer regarding array of ranges), you can make use of `reduce` as follows

```
let arr = [1...5, 11...15].reduce([]) { $0.0 + Array($0.1) }
```

Or, alternatively, `flatten`

```
var arr = Array([1...5, 11...15].flatten())
```

Both the above yields the following result

```
print(arr.dynamicType) // Array<Int>
print(arr)             // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply concatenate the arrays created from each range:

```
let array = Array(10 ... 14) + Array(1 ... 24)
```

Alternatively:

```
let array = [10 ... 14, 1 ... 4].flatMap { $0 }
```

which has the small advantage of not creating intermediate arrays
(as you can see in the open source implementation https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift.gyb).

Answer (score 1):

For an array of ranges you define the array as

```
let array: [Range<Int>] = [0...1, 5...100]
```

and so on and so forth.

Comment: @dfri Post that as an answer!