# Retrieving and casting data from an array in Parse and SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, heroku, parse-platform

This error always show when I try to retrieve and append the elements of an array in Parse to an array created in the code:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10b281b60) to 'NSString'
>   (0x10bdc5b48).

However, when I use print, it works with no errors and I can get the data

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "Courses")

 query.whereKey("subject", equalTo: "\((object["course"] as! String))")                        
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in

 if let objects = objects
 {
     for object in objects
     {                       
         print(object["subject"] as! String)
         self.courses.append(object["subject"] as! String)
         print(object.valueForKey("timeToShow")!)  
         // it works to print the elemnts in array from parse self.dates.append((object.valueForKey("timeToShow") as! String))  
         // this line shows the error down !

         self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
}
```

[image: Picture with more details]

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: this line 
        self.courses.append(object["subject"] as! String)

Comment: And what is self.courses defined as? Is it a String array? Because `object["subject']` is clearly an array (as the print statement shows) so that wouldn't work.

Comment: (object["subject"]) is not the deal it is defined as a string 

self.dates.append((object.valueForKey("timeToShow") as! String))  is the problem
dates is defined as an array of strings and i want to retrieve from parse an array and i want to append them to dates which is again an array of strings

Comment: How is `object["subject"]`  not the issue, you said that is where the error is occurring..

Comment: self.dates.append((object.valueForKey("timeToShow") as! String)) // this line shows the error down 

the error is in this code   i said this

Answer (score 3):

From what you said:

1. `self.dates` is an array of type `String`
2. `object.valueForKey("timeToShow")` is an array of type `String`
3. You want to append the values in `object.valueForKey("timeToShow")` to the end of `self.dates`

So instead of casting to a String and trying to append, you need to append all of the values of the array (note this depends on the version of Swift that you are using):

```
let times = object.valueForKey("timeToShow") as! [String]
self.dates += times 

// Or:
self.dates.extend(times) // Swift 1.2
self.dates.appendContentsOf(btimes) // Swift 2
self.dates.append(contentsOf: times) // Swift 3
```

Appending an array to another array taken from [this StackOverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25146530/854730).

Comment: in the second line there is an error "Binary operator +=cannot be applied  of type ['String'] and 'AnyObject'
what is the alternative way to do it =( ?

Comment: @AhmadKhawatmi just updated the answer, you need to cast the `AnyObject` to `[String]` (`let times = object.valueForKey("timeToShow") as! [String]
`)

Comment: AnyObject to [String] (let times = object.valueForKey("timeToShow") as! [String] )   it didnt work =(
but i just solved it with your help using another tricky way after trying for hours lol

i used this 
var times = object.valueForKey("timeToShow")!
 times = String(times)
  self.dates.append(times as! String)

sorry for the confusion that i made
and thanks a lot Carter =)