# How to merge multiple arrays in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have several classes look like this:

```
class A {}
class A1 : A {}
class A2 : A {}

class A3 : A {}
class A4 : A {}

class main {
    var a1 : A1
    var a2 : A2
    var a3s : [A3]
    var a4s : [A4]

    func getAll() -> [A] {
        return ([a1, a2] + a3s + a4s)
    }
}
```

If you take a look on function getAll(), you will see I try to return an Array of all object with type is the base class A. However, I always get the error:

> "Binary operator '+(*:*:)' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Any]' and '[a3s]'"

Do you know what the proper way is in this case?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146382/how-do-i-concatenate-or-merge-arrays-in-swift

Comment: So, the expected output is: One array that contains all of the elements in the four arrays, is it correct?

Comment: Not really duplicated question. The difference is an array of type which is subclass of the base class.

Comment: Here is another one (just for the fun of it) `return [[a1, a2], a3s, a4s].flatMap{ $0 as? [A] }.reduce([], +)` or in more adventurous flavor `return [[a1, a2], a3s, a4s].flatMap{ $0 as! [A] }`

Comment: @Alladinian No need for the reduce.  Also forced downcasts are evil.  I have SwiftLint set up to mark that as a compile error.

Comment: @Samah Well, you just did break down the 'fun' & 'adventurous' parts of my comment :P Agreed. That's why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: @Alladinian I'm never fun nor adventurous. ;)

Comment: Do you how to merge two arrays so that any element of one array that are found in the other array shows up only once the the resultant single array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's just a problem of casting correctly the arrays, you may solve it doing so:

```
func getAll() -> [A] {
    return ([a1, a2] as [A] + a3s as [A] + a4s)
}
```

---

Just for fun: if you want to solve it dynamically you might use the reflection in this way:

```
class A {}
class A1 : A {}
class A2 : A {}
class A3 : A {}
class A4 : A {}

class main {
    var a1 = A1()
    var a2 = A2()
    var a3s : [A3] = [A3()]
    var a4s : [A4] = [A4(), A4()]

    func getAll() -> [A] {
        var res = [A]()
        Mirror(reflecting:self).children.forEach {
            if let a = $0.value as? A {
                res.append(a)
            } else if let aArray = $0.value as? [A] {
                res.append(contentsOf: aArray)
            }
        }
        return res
    }
}

let all = main().getAll()
print(all) //A1, A2, A3, A4, A4
```

Comment: @chipbk10 It's quite complicate :)

Comment: It's not really a complicated use case.  There's no reason to have all those casts if you declare a variable with the correct type.

Comment: @Samah sure, however in the question is written `Binary operator '+(::)' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Any]' and '[a3s]'`: my answer was trying to be pertinent to such question.

Comment: There's a difference between answering the question and solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a cleaner way, I guess.

```
func getAll() -> [A] {
    let all: [[A]] = [[a1], [a2], a3s, a4s]
    return all.flatMap{$0}
}
```

This creates an array of arrays, then uses a `flatMap` to flatten them into a single array.

Comment: even, you code is cleaner, but I guess, the computation is expensive.

Comment: How is that expensive?  A flatmap on a 4 element array.

Comment: but if each element array is consist of 1000 elements ?

Comment: Then you certainly shouldn't be appending arrays.

Comment: @chipbk10 Would it be in your case?

Comment: I mean, if you compare your solution and the accepted solution, the computation in your case is more.

Comment: Slight nitpick,`[[a1], [a2], a3s, a4s]` can be written as `[[a1, a2], a3s, a4s]`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the compiler thinks you are trying to add `[Any]` and `[A3]`. This is because the type of `[a1, a2] is [Any]`and `a3s is [A3]`. But the operator `+` cannot do that.

As others have pointed out, you can cast the arrays in your statement to `[A]` so the `+` operator can do his job.

Since you mentioned that you have several classes, it might be a good idea to create a function that you can reuse and that can infer the type correctly.

```
func merge<T>(_ array: [T]...) -> [T] {
    return array.flatMap { $0 }
}

func getAll() -> [A] {
    return merge([a1, a2], a3s, a4s)
}
```

Comment: Right. The take-away here is that an array of `[ClassA, ClassB]` is type `[Any]` unless you cast it, even if `ClassA` and `ClassB` have a common base class. It would be nice if, in your example, the compiler would make an array of `[A1, A1]` be type `[A]`, but it doesn't.

Comment: Exactly, I am missing your first point in my answer. I don't understand the second part. Running `array.forEach { print(type(of: $0)) }` inside the `merge(_:)` function prints `Array<A>`. Even if you pass `[a1, a1]` as a parameter.