# Flatten all values of multiple arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a Dictionary of Integer Arrays like below:

`let numbers = [1: [2, 3], 4: [5, 6, 7], 8: [9]]`

What I really want is a single flattened Array of all of the values (which themselves are arrays), like so:

`[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]`

Now, I have been able to call `numbers.values.array` to get:

`[[2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [9]]`

But what I'm looking for is to merge these one step further, flattening them.

Does Swift (1.1, or 1.2) offer a convenience method for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible solution is

```
[].join(numbers.values)
```

And if you want the values in the order corresponding to the sorted
dictionary *keys* then it would be

```
flatMap(sorted(numbers.keys)) { numbers[$0]! }
```

Comment: Although it is ambiguous, I would assume that you want to sort the final value array, not sort the dictionary keys.  So sorted(flatMap(numbers.keys){numbers[$0]!})  Never mind, I see your comment above.

Answer (score 7):

With a combination of `numbers.values.array` and a `reduce` function you can simplify this down in one line of code.

```
numbers.values.array.reduce([], combine: +) // [5,6,7,2,3,9]
```

However, I would like to note that since you are using a dictionary, you cannot guarantee that the values will be sorted, so you can use the `sorted` function to accomplish this:

```
sorted(numbers.values.array.reduce([], combine: +), <) // [2,3,5,6,7,9]
```

As @Jeffery Thomas stated, you can also use flatmap which was just added in Swift 1.2:

```
sorted(numbers.values.array.flatMap { $0 }, <)
```

And to take it a step further, using the global `sorted` function, the `<` is extraneous because it is the default and using the global `reduce` and `flatMap` functions, you can remove the `array` property as pointed out by Martin R, so it can be reduced down to:

```
sorted(reduce(numbers.values, [], +))
sorted(flatMap(numbers.values) { $0 })
```

Answer (score 5):

This is called [flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift), and it's a relatively common operation. There are a number of ways to do it, so pick one that suits your needs.

```
numbers.values.array.reduce([], combine: +) // As stated by @Bluehound
reduce(numbers.values, [], +)
numbers.values.array.flatMap { $0 } // Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3)
flatMap(numbers.values) { $0 } // Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3)
```

`flatMap` may be the most useful, if the next step after flattening is mapping.

NOTE: Thanks @MartinR for the syntax tip.

Comment: Or `flatMap(numbers.values) { $0 }`, you don't need the `array` property.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the tip, both `flatMap` and `reduce` could be passed `numbers.values`.