# How can I flatten an array swiftily in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, flatten

I want to turn this:

```
let x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

into this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

very gracefully.

The most straightforward way, of course, is

```
var y = [Int]()
x.forEach { y.appendContentsOf($0) }
```

But that makes the resulting array mutable, which is unnecessary. I don't like this way.

I tried using `reduce`:

```
let y = x.reduce([Int]()) { (array, ints) -> [Int] in
    array.appendContentsOf(ints)
    return array
}
```

But the compiler complains that `array` is immutable, so I can't call the mutating method `appendContentsOf`.

Hence, I added some stuff:

```
let y = x.reduce([Int]()) { (array, ints) -> [Int] in
    var newArr = array
    newArr.appendContentsOf(ints)
    return newArr
}
```

This is just *plain bad*. I have an instinct that this is not swifty.

How can I flatten an array more swiftily than the above methods? A one-liner would be good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten a Array of Arrays in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a built-in function for this called [`joined`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/2431985-joined):

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].joined()
```

(Note that this doesn't actually return another Array, it returns a `FlattenSequence`, but that usually doesn't matter because it's still a sequence that you can use with `for` loops and whatnot. If you really care, you can use `Array(arrayOfArrays.joined())`.)

---

The [`flatMap` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641332-flatmap) can also help you out. Its signature is, roughly,

```
flatMap<S: SequenceType>(fn: (Generator.Element) -> S) -> [S.Generator.Element]
```

This means that you can pass a `fn` which for any element returns a sequence, and it'll combine/concatenate those sequences.

Since your array's elements are themselves sequences, you can use a function which just returns the element itself (`{ x in return x }` or equivalently just `{$0}`):

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].flatMap{ $0 }
```

Comment: Oh I see! I have looked at `flatMap` before. But I was looking at the wrong one - `flatMap(transform: ([Int]) -> T? throws) rethrows -> [T]`. I was wondering "how is this different from `map`?" Now I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Yes! There are multiple kinds of flatMap. Go read about monads, and you might understand why they have the same name :-)

Comment: Good to know ! I thought we had to cast the type before looping, glad to see we don't :)

Answer (score 9):

With Swift 5, you can choose one of the **three following ways** in order to flatten an array.

---

### #1. Flatten an array with `Array`'s `flatMap(_:)` method

With Swift, types that conform to `Sequence` protocol (including `Array`) have a `flatMap(_:)` method. `Array`'s [`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126947-flatmap) has the following declaration:

```
func flatMap<SegmentOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> SegmentOfResult) rethrows -> [SegmentOfResult.Element] where SegmentOfResult : Sequence
```

> Returns an array containing the concatenated results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

The Playground sample code below shows how to flatten an `Array` of type `[[Int]]` to type `[Int]` using `flatMap(_:)`:

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
let flattenArray = array.flatMap({ (element: [Int]) -> [Int] in
    return element
})
print(flattenArray) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

### #2. Flatten an array with `Array`'s `joined()` method

`Array`'s has a method called `joined()`. [`joined()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945737-joined) has the following declaration:

```
func joined() -> FlattenSequence<Array<Element>>
```

> Returns the elements of this sequence of sequences, concatenated.

The following Playground sample code shows how to flatten an `Array` of type `[[Int]]` to type `[Int]` using `joined()`:

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
let flattenCollection = array.joined()
let flattenArray = Array(flattenCollection)
print(flattenArray) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

### #3. Flatten an array with `Array`'s `reduce(_:_:)` method

Swift `Array` has a [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) method with the following declaration:

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

> Returns the result of combining the elements of the sequence using the given closure.

The following Playground sample code shows how to flatten an `Array` of type `[[Int]]` to type `[Int]` using `reduce(_:_:)`:

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
let flattenArray = array.reduce([], { (result: [Int], element: [Int]) -> [Int] in
    return result + element
})
print(flattenArray) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As an alternative to `reduce(_:_:)`, you can use [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce):

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
let flattenArray = array.reduce(into: [Int]()) { (result: inout [Int], element: [Int]) in
    result += element
}
print(flattenArray) // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use 2 function to do that

1. joined()
2. compactMap

   let y = x.compactMap{$0}.joined().compactMap{$0}

[Reference for more about FlattenSequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/flattensequence)

Answer (score -1):

**Flatten function in Array :**

```
let x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
let y = Array(x.flatten())
print(y)
```

**flatMap function in Array :**

```
let x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
let y = x.flatMap({$0})
print(y)
```

**Your Output :**

[image]

For more : [**Array in Swift**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/04/array-in-swift.html)

Comment: There isn't flatten method on Array structure in Swift, instead there is joined method.