# Get only the string value from NSArray output

Tags: arrays, swift

I am storing values from Json response like

```
self.NameArray = self.attachmentsArray.valueForKey("filename") as! NSArray
```

Output:

```
NameArray(("Din.pdf","img.jpeg"),(),(),("41_58"))
```

I got this output. I need to get the array only having `("Din.pdf","img.jpeg","41_58")`.

How to get it using swift code?

Comment: what is the type of your `NameArray`?

Comment: Its not duplicate. Is it??

Comment: NameArray is in NSArray

Comment: I can't answer now, its been marked duplicate.

Comment: No its doesn't, flatmap gives different result than what user wants, OP wants to emit empty arrays too. Kindly open it and I'll give the answer.

Comment: Apologies, it does!

Comment: @Mr.UB Actually now that OP has told us they have an NSArray, the linked answers would not be sufficient since OP would have to cast their NSArray to a Swift array first ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOx037lpi1JMsKqQjCVBj3x3YTQuQ7FQQEc)).

Comment: Yes, OP'll need to convert the `NSArray` into `[[String]]` Type. http://imgur.com/sTgRy7W

Comment: @Mr.UB Re-opened. In your answer, please also give a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift it will be useful for readers anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I'd use `flat` (to get only "1" level), and `filter` to keep only the strings not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert `NSArray` to Swift Type `[[String]]`:

  ```
  let NameArray:NSArray = [["Din.pdf","img.jpeg"], [], [], [ "41_58" ]]

  let swiftArray = NameArray as! [[String]]

  let flattenedArray = swiftArray.flatMap{ $0 }
  ```

Credits: [Eric Aya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/eric-aya) and [Flatten a Array of Arrays in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift)

- If you do not want to convert it into Swift Type:

  ```
  let NameArray:NSArray = [["Din.pdf","img.jpeg"], [], [], [ "41_58" ]]

  let arrFiltered:NSMutableArray! = []

  for arr in NameArray {
      for a in arr as! NSArray {
          arrFiltered.addObject(a)
      }
  }

  print(arrFiltered)
  ```