# Heterogeneous collection literal in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to read nested array as follows but getting an error.

```
var inputArray = [1,[4,3],6,[5,[1,0]]] 

func nestedArray(inputArray :[Any])
{

}
```

> error: heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to
>   '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional var
>   inputArray = [1,[4,3],6,[5,[1,0]]]

Comment: The error tells you how to fix this.

Comment: Xcode even offers to insert `as [Any]` – you only have to click on the "Fix" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
var inputArray:[Any] = [1,[4,3],6,[5,[1,0]]]
```

as you specify elements of different types Int , Array and nested Array

Comment: How could I able to read an item in this nested Array, like first and second item iteratively?

Comment: you need if else or switch cases of castable options like **element as? Int** , or **element as? [Int]** or **element as? [Any]** respectively

Comment: could you please illustrate with an example, I am trying to flatten this nested Array into a regular array?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift