# SwiftUi multiple foreach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've this situation in the new SwiftUI, I've a problem to create duoble foreach

```
struct LineupMod {
    var id: Int = 0
    var mod: Int = 0
    var name: [String] = []
}
```

This In my view

```
@ObservedObject var lineupMod = LineupViewModel()
-
-
-
                           ForEach(self.lineupMod.lineupMod, id: \.self) { module in
                                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20, content: {
                                    ForEach(module.name) { name in
                                        Group {
                                            Spacer()
                                            VStack {
                                                Image("Wanda_Nara")
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                                                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1))
                                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                                Text(name)
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            }
                                            Spacer()
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            }
```

Why the code not build? In LineupViewModel i get data from server
thanks

Comment: If the code doesn't build I assume you get a build error(s)?

Comment: This error: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Comment: What happens if you add the `id:` parameter as well for the inner loop? Another posiible option is to flatten the array of arrays to a single array of names before doing `ForEach`

Comment: I can't change the array because for what I have to show I need it like this

Comment: You won't change the array, just make a new local one to be used for this view. Example from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift) on how to flatten an array of arrays

Comment: Can you write an example for my view?

Comment: `let names = self.lineUpMod.lineUpMod.flatMap { $0.name }`, now you can do `ForEach` on `names`

Answer (score 1):

try do this. It's always interesting that the id is of type UUID.

```
struct LineupMod: Hashable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var mod: Int = 0
    var name: [String] = []

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

```
ForEach(lineupMod.lineupMod, id: \.self) { module in
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20, content: {
                ForEach(module.name, id: \.self) { name in
                    Group {
                        Spacer()
                        VStack {
                            Image("Wanda_Nara")
                                .resizable()
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .shadow(radius: 10)
                                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1))
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            Text(name)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```