# Is flatMap deprecated or not in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, generics, high-order-component

```
print([ [1, 2], [3, 4]].flatMap{_ in })
```

[image: screenshot of the example code with a warning that flatMap is deprecated]

Comment: Replace `_ in` with `$0` and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

One particular overload of `flatMap` has been deprecated. [It's the `flatMap` method of `Sequence` with this signature:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907182-flatmap)

> ```swift
> func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(
>     _ transform: (Self.Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?
> ) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
> ```

And it has been deprecated since Swift 4.1. You can learn more about why it was deprecated by watching [episode 10 of Point-Free, “A Tale of Two Flat-Maps”](https://www.pointfree.co/episodes/ep10-a-tale-of-two-flat-maps). (That episode is free to watch.)

However, the compiler is forced to pick that deprecated overload of `flatMap` here.

For [the non-deprecated version of `flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap), the `transform` function must return some type of `Sequence`. That's the whole point of (non-deprecated) `flatMap`: each element of the input is turned into some `Sequence`, and those `Sequence`s are concatenated (flattened) into a single output array.

But your `transform` returns `Void`, and `Void` (which is an alias for the empty tuple, `()`) is **not** a `Sequence`. So the compiler **can't** use the non-deprecated `flatMap`.

The compiler can, however, implicitly promote your `transform` to return an `Optional<Void>`, which then lets the compiler use the deprecated `flatMap` to compile the code.

The correct way to write your statement is to use `map` instead of `flatMap`, because you're returning a single value (`()`) rather than a `Sequence`:

```swift
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].map { _ in }
```