# Swift: How to merge several sets of String?

Tags: swift, set

Hello I have this case:

```
enum Test {
    static let all: [Test] = [.a, .b, .c]
   
    case a, b, c

    var chars: Set<String> {
        switch self {
            case .a: 
                return ["a", "b", "c"]
            case .b: 
                return ["d", "e", "f"]
            case .c: 
                return ["g", "h", "i"]
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to create a set that maps all the chars from all the cases, so the result would be:

> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]

I tried this:

```
static var allCharacters: Set<String> {
    return Test.all
        .joined()
        .flatMap { $0.chars }
}
```

But this doesn't work. What should I do?

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 static var allCharacters: Set<String> {
     return Set(Test.all.flatMap { $0.chars })
 }
```

OR

```
 static var allCharacters: Set<String> {
     let res =  Test.all.map { $0.chars }
     return res.reduce(into: Set()) { partialResult, arr in
         partialResult = partialResult.union(arr)
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you are using `union` (as opposed to `formUnion`), you might as well use the other overload of `reduce`, the one without the `into:`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
let allStrings = Test.all.reduce(into: Set()) { acc, newSet in 
    acc.formUnion(newSet.chars) 
}
```

`reduce` starts with `Set()` as the `acc`, and for each `newSet` in `Test.all`, does `acc.formUnion(newSet.chars)`. As a whole, this computes the union of all the sets in `Test.all.map(\.chars)`.

Notes:

- `Test` can conform to `CaseIterable`. Then you don't need to declare `all`. An `allCases` property will be automatically generated for you.
- There is no `joined` method on an array of `Test`s. [`joined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/joined()) is available on sequences of sequences, and returns a `FlattenSequence`, which is not what you want.